# Send Images from React Native to PHP Symfony server

Tags: php, react-native, symfony, fetch

I'm trying to send three images and some text fields in one request from `React Native` client to my `PHP Symfony` server. This is my `ReactNative` code:

```
 const onSubmitPress = async () => {
        let formData = new FormData();

        await formData.append('title', textTitle);
        await formData.append('description', textDescription);
        await formData.append('latitude', latitude);
        await formData.append('longitude', longitude);
        await formData.append('photoAuthor', photoAuthor);
        await formData.append('textAuthor', textAuthor);
        await formData.append('region', region);

        await images.map(image =>
            formData.append('photo', {
                uri: image.uri,
                name: image.filename,
                type: image.mediaType,
            }));
        let responseTypes = await fetch('https://website.ru/api/send_place_to_moderation', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'API-Access-Key': 'code'
            },
            body: formData
        })
 }
```

And this is my server side code which is on `PHP Symfony 5`
Here I'm trying to get this data but it is always emtpy.

```
 global $request;
        $apiKey = $request->headers->get('API-Access-Key');
        if ($apiKey == 'code') {
            $placeForModerationFromClient = json_decode($request->getContent());

            $newPlaceForModeration = new Moderation();
            $newPlaceForModeration->setDescription($placeForModerationFromClient['description']);
            $newPlaceForModeration->setLatitude($placeForModerationFromClient['latitude']);
            $newPlaceForModeration->setLongitude($placeForModerationFromClient['longitude']);
            $newPlaceForModeration->setPhotoAuthor($placeForModerationFromClient['photoAuthor']);
            $newPlaceForModeration->setRegion($placeForModerationFromClient['region']);
            $newPlaceForModeration->setTextAuthor($placeForModerationFromClient['textAuthor']);
            $newPlaceForModeration->setTitle($placeForModerationFromClient['title']);
            $em->persist($newPlaceForModeration);
            $em->flush();
            return new Response($placeForModerationFromClient, 200);
        } else {
            return new Response('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
    }
```

Error message: `<!-- Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Moderation::setDescription() must be of the type string, null given`

When I try to send only text fields without this `new FormData()` and using `Content-Type: 'application/json'` it works fine, but I need to send images, so I use this `Content-Type: 'multipart/form-data'` and append everything to new FormData and when I try to get request body like this `$placeForModerationFromClient = json_decode($request->getContent());` it is empty.

Before sending request I logged my `formData`:

```
FormData {
  "_parts": Array [
    Array [
      "title",
      "Title of the place",
    ],
    Array [
      "description",
      "Description of the place",
    ],
    Array [
      "latitude",
      "14.35644",
    ],
    Array [
      "longitude",
      "27.24565",
    ],
    Array [
      "photoAuthor",
      "Andrey",
    ],
    Array [
      "textAuthor",
      "Andrey",
    ],
    Array [
      "region",
      "amurskaya",
    ],
    Array [
      "photo",
      Object {
        "name": "IMG_3534.PNG",
        "type": "photo",
        "uri": "assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=B82C4611-B698-47A6-A6BA-34840BD3DDB0&ext=PNG",
      },
    ],
    Array [
      "photo",
      Object {
        "name": "IMG_3533.PNG",
        "type": "photo",
        "uri": "assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=F84D3D46-2BF2-4E33-B698-E703A30D840A&ext=PNG",
      },
    ],
    Array [
      "photo",
      Object {
        "name": "IMG_3532.PNG",
        "type": "photo",
        "uri": "assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=76713216-2930-4934-879E-A033D33157C0&ext=PNG",
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```

So it's not empty.

Maybe it is wrong to put `FormData` to `body` or maybe with `multipart/form-data` I shouldn't use `body` at all?

Comment: What is the output from `dd($request->getContent());` and why are you using  `global $request;`?

Comment: @WillB. It seems I found out what had happend. The thing is data is to huge. Now when I'm sending only one image it works. I'm using `global $request` because I think it's easier then write this:                                                                                                    `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
public function sendPlaceToModeration(Request $request) ` Is it wrong?

Comment: As a general rule, it is considered best practice to avoid the use of the `global` keyword. The issue may be related to [`post_max_size`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) and/or [`upload_max_filesize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) being set too low.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with @willb, using `global $request` is very nasty